# Flask-Login: Errors With Specific Attributes

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm trying to create and use a User function that works with Flask-Login as follows:

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    passhash = db.Column(db.String(160))
    posts = db.relationship('Idea', backref='user')

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.passhash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def __str__(self):
        return "User: " + self.username + " Hash: " + self.passhash

    # Managing passwords using Werkzeug security library
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.passhash, password)

    # Necessary functions for Flask-Login session management
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        # Anonymous users aren't supported
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.username)
```

However, when trying to use this code, I see the error:

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Coming across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26608805/1195935), I tried to fix this by changing the function from `class User(db.Model)` to `class User(db.Model, UserMixin)`, even though I'm manually implementing the methods. While doing this eliminated the above error, I started seeing:

> NotImplementedError: No `id` attribute - override `get_id`

What am I doing wrong here? While I don't have an attribute named `id`, I have set up the `get_id` function (as above). Is there a particular reason why the functions above aren't being picked up?

The errors occur in particular when I pass my `user = User.query.get(form.username.data)` to `login_user()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, there was no problem with the implementation of the code. It turns out that my text editor had mixed up indents and spaces in some places, leading to the weird errors.

Answer (score 2):

How did you set up the [user_loader](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.LoginManager.user_loader)? You must pass it a user instance like so:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.filter(User.id == int(user_id)).first()
```

[Example](https://github.com/mjhea0/flask-basic-registration/blob/master/project/__init__.py#L58).

Comment: I set it up to `return User.query.get(username)`

Answer (score 1):

You should add id column in User class

`id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)`

then set up the user_loader

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.filter(User.id==int(id)).first()
```